# Using a positive lookahead to remove the middle of a string

Tags: regex

I'm currently attempting to remove text in the middle of this string:

```
RenameMe_12345_12365_130706T234502.txt
```

using the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?=_[0-9]+_[0-9]+).+$
```

in an attempt to return:

```
RenameMe_130706T234502.txt
```

but the regex returns the entire string without excluding the middle:

```
RenameMe_12345_12365_130706T234502.txt
```

Am I using the positive lookahead incorrectly, or am I approaching the problem incorrectly? Can positive lookaheads not be used this way?

Comment: If you want to remove the middle, you could capture the front and back and concatenate those together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this regex:

```
_.*_
```

with

```
_
```

example with `sed` tool:

```
kent$  echo RenameMe_12345_12365_130706T234502.txt|sed 's/_.*_/_/'
RenameMe_130706T234502.txt
```

You could do it with your own tool/programming language.

**EDIT** for OP's comment:

@CodingUnderDuress `_.*_` is a single regex (BRE). It uses the `.*` greedy character to achieve your goal.

If you don't want to do the substitution, just with regex to match the parts you need, you could do:

```
(^[^_]*|_[^_]*$)
```

test with grep: (-E means ERE)

```
kent$  echo "RenameMe_12345_12365_130706T234502.txt"|grep -Eo '(^[^_]*|_[^_]*$)' 
RenameMe
_130706T234502.txt
```

You can of course use look-behind/ahead, if you really love them. then you need PCRE. And I don't see why we need use look-around here for your requirement.

Comment: Correct.  I typically frown on using the dot, but this would work perfect.  `_\w*_` would also work and would be faster, because `\w` includes underscores but doesn't include periods.  But we're talking 5 cpu cycles faster, nothing at all.  `_[\d_]*_` would be the fastest, assuming the "middle" was always digits.  +1

Comment: Well speedwise, `\d` is may also include unicode versions of numbers. So  it would be significantly faster to use the character class `[0-9]` instead of a `\d`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just out of curiosity, is it not possible to do this using a single regex and a lookahead, then?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the contents of this by a empty character

```
_(\w+(?=_))*
```

Working

```
[1] Match the character `_`
[2] followed a set of word characters
[3] I have used positive look-ahead `?=_` to make sure the last `_` is not missed out
[4] Match the above 0 or more times
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
(?<=[^_])_\w+_(?=[^_]+)
```

to match the part you want to remove.